# How to export Jupyter notebook in one page?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I want to export a Jupyter notebook to pdf as one inseparable page. It is one inseparable page ([picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGRTF.png)) in `.ipynb` file, however when I try to save it as pdf, neither `download as pdf` nor `ctrl+P` give a desired output i.e. it is a file with many pages: [picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vggnW.png)
Is it possible to export it exactly as it is in the `.ipynb` without separation into pages (otherwise the output is not very pretty)?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know with jupyter-notebook but with jupyter-lab you can just click File->Export->As PDF

[image: Illustration of export as pdf]